# Why does my Facebook profile say I have photos and albums when I don't have any?

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos

I have deleted all my photos and albums from my Facebook profile in order to do some "spring cleaning" and I have realised that even if I have 0 photos it still says: "3 Photos of you", "36 photos", "12 albums".

[image]

I would like to know if I can remove the counts somehow, as my friends are telling me I do not want to show my pictures to them.

Comment: So this is what _you_ see in _your_ account, right? It’s _not_ what _others_ see in your account.

Comment: No, is what others see as well. I went to the option view profile as:.... and I put there a friend's name. :(

Comment: If others see it this way, it could be due to some privacy setting, so it would be “normal”—if you would have pictures there. However, if you see it this way and there are no pictures inside, it’s not normal. Have you tried emptying cache/history/cookies?

Comment: Yeah I did, plus I used my account on other computers as well; same story. I do not think is the browser's fault. Thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: It looks like a bug then. What happens if you try to upload a new photo or make a new album? Do the counters change?

Comment: Yes. I tried to make a new album and it went to 13. Then I delete it and went back to 12. It's stuck somewhere.

Comment: Well, looks like a Facebook cache/caching problem and if it’s indeed so, there’s nothing you can do but wait.